# removing a spliced item from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, drop-down-menu

I have  a list of items in a dropdown and currently whenever i click/select one of the dropdown items it is added to a different array and then i would like to have it removed from the list.

This is what i have:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of dropdownlist ">
    <a (click)="select(item) " class="dropdown-item ">
        <i class="fa fa-fw " [ngClass]="{ 'fa-check': item.checked, 'glyphicon-none': !item.checked} "></i>
    </a>
</li>

 select(item: any) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;
    this.containers.push(item);
    this.dropdownlist.splice(item.checked);
  }

 dropdownlist: Array<any> = [];

 containers: Array<Panel> = [
     new Panel(1, 'Test1', 'export data', 'test data in modal'),
     new Panel(2, 'Test2','export image', 'more test data'),
     new Panel(3, 'Test3', 'export data', 'more and more data')
 ];
```

My problem is that when the dropdown only has one item and i try to add it to the other array it doesn't get removed from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) can take multiple arguments:

```
array.splice(start)
array.splice(start, deleteCount)
array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, ...)
```

In your case to ensure you only delete the item you want, make sure the second argument = `1` and that you pass in the index of the item you want to remove:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of dropdownlist; let i = index ">
    <a (click)="select(item, i) " class="dropdown-item ">
        <i class="fa fa-fw " [ngClass]="{ 'fa-check': item.checked, 'glyphicon-none': !item.checked} "></i>
    </a>
</li>

select(item: any, index: number) {
     item.checked = !item.checked;
     this.containers.push(item);
     this.dropdownlist.splice(index, 1);
}
```